# Angularjs how to get api in a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been searching for hours and hours and couldn't find something that I need. Can any kind soul out there please help me out? I am try to translate something like this from my controller :

```
      myApp.controller('displayCatController', ['$scope','$http','$q', 'displayAll', function($scope, $http, $q, displayAll){


              var CombinedName = [];
              //Display auditoriums information
              var CategoryAudit  = $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url:'https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=auditoriums&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4ODY2MTM3LCJleHAiOjE1MzkyOTgxMzcsIm5iZiI6MTUzODg2NjEzNywianRpIjoiOWZhMDVmZDUzNGRhNjU1ZDQ3YTgwODdmMGZkYjY1OGEifQ.2RbY7CGZY5hRfKZHVBels1XUDiAh9zU2lyUvePF8dXk'
                  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.auditoriums = response.data.SrchResults;
                    $scope.auditoriums.splice(0,1);
                  }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  });

              //Display exhibitions information
              var CategoryExhibit = $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                  url: 'https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=exhibitioncentres&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4ODY2MTM3LCJleHAiOjE1MzkyOTgxMzcsIm5iZiI6MTUzODg2NjEzNywianRpIjoiOWZhMDVmZDUzNGRhNjU1ZDQ3YTgwODdmMGZkYjY1OGEifQ.2RbY7CGZY5hRfKZHVBels1XUDiAh9zU2lyUvePF8dXk'
                        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                            $scope.exhibitions = response.data.SrchResults;
                    $scope.exhibitions.splice(0,1);
                        }, function errorCallback(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        });


                // To combine all the $http API into one
                $q.all([CategoryAudit, CategoryExhibit, CategoryHotel]).then(function(){
                $scope.combine = $scope.exhibitions.concat($scope.auditoriums, $scope.hotels);
                // For loop to get only the names
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.combine.length; i++){
                    if (i >= 0){
                        CombinedName.push($scope.combine[i].NAME);
                    }
                }

            });

      }]);
```

into a factory where I can place my $http call in there to make it cleaner.
I would really really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Refer below sample code for factory and controller usage..

```js
//Factory
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

    var urlBase = '/api/customers';
    var dataFactory = {};

    dataFactory.getCustomers = function() {
      return $http.get(urlBase);
    };

    return dataFactory;
  }]);

//Controller
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', 'dataFactory',
    function($scope, dataFactory) {
      $scope.customers;

      getCustomers();

      function getCustomers() {
        dataFactory.getCustomers()
          .then(function(response) {
            $scope.customers = response.data;
          }, function(error) {
            console.log(error.message;)
          });
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you have just write factory function and separate out the code from your controller. Refer the below code.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('displayCatController', ['$scope','MyService', function($scope, MyService){

              // Display auditoriums information
              $scope.getCategoryAuditData = function(){
               MyService.CategoryAudit().then(function (response){
                $scope.CategoryAudit = response.data;
               
                  }, function(error) {
                    console.log(error)
                  });
              }
              
           // Display exhibitions information
              $scope.getCategoryExhibitData = function(){
               MyService.CategoryAudit().then(function (response){
                $scope.CategoryAudit = response.data;
                
                  }, function(error) {
                    console.log(error)
                  });
              }
              
              $scope.getCategoryAuditData();
              $scope.getCategoryAuditData();
      }])
      
 .factory('MyService', function($http) {
  
  var factory = {}; 

  factory.CategoryAudit = function() {
   return $http.get('https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=auditoriums&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4ODY2MTM3LCJleHAiOjE1MzkyOTgxMzcsIm5iZiI6MTUzODg2NjEzNywianRpIjoiOWZhMDVmZDUzNGRhNjU1ZDQ3YTgwODdmMGZkYjY1OGEifQ.2RbY7CGZY5hRfKZHVBels1XUDiAh9zU2lyUvePF8dXk');
  }

  factory.CategoryExhibit = function() {
   $http.get('https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=exhibitioncentres&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4ODY2MTM3LCJleHAiOjE1MzkyOTgxMzcsIm5iZiI6MTUzODg2NjEzNywianRpIjoiOWZhMDVmZDUzNGRhNjU1ZDQ3YTgwODdmMGZkYjY1OGEifQ.2RbY7CGZY5hRfKZHVBels1XUDiAh9zU2lyUvePF8dXk');
  }

  return factory;
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="displayCatController">
 <h1>Hello</h1>
 <hr>
 <h1>Response</h1>
 <p>{{CategoryAudit}}</p>
 <hr>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="displayCatController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For more detail and learning refer [Link](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/)

Hope this will help you...